# how to run aspx files on windows XP

Tags: asp.net

I have windows xp service pack 3 so i cannot download some of the proggrams.

I downloaded the next proggrams:
*visual c++ 2005 express edition(by the way it's imposibble to find the visual studio express edition of 2005 on microsoft download center)

*microsoft web platformer installer
*windows installer
*microsoft .net framework 2.0 service pack 1

*microsoft sql server 2005 express edition

and i still cannot run aspx files. everytime im trying to open an aspx file it opens it as text file, and doesnt allow me to run it(the file worked on other computers).
I assume the problem is in my visual studio version, can someone give me a link to a visual studio that will work for me(p.s if I need to download new sql server proggram or net framework I'll appriciate if you tell me as well).

and remember that I have winxp so I cant download visual studio 2012(p.s there is a way you can somehow devolop without paying for the software?)

any help will be apperciate.
Tnx Dean.

Answer (score 0):

You need Visual Studio Web Developer Express and not Visual C++ Express Edition. Here is the link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=51413&clcid=0x409
And here you have 2008 - should work on XP too - http://www.asp.net/downloads/essential